# What is a scoped DNS query?

Tags: macos, networking, dns, domain

In Mac OS X (Mavericks) I see multiple resolvers, and I don't understand the difference between scoped and non-scoped DNS query resolvers as displayed below:

```
$ scutil --dns
DNS configuration

resolver #1
  search domain[1] : test
  nameserver[0] : 172.31.30.10
  flags    : Request A records
  reach    : Reachable

.... <arpa stuff snipped> ...
resolver #6
  domain   : 9.e.f.ip6.arpa
  options  : mdns
  timeout  : 5
  flags    : Request A records
  order    : 300600

DNS configuration (for scoped queries) 

resolver #1
  search domain[0] : test
  nameserver[0] : 172.31.30.10
  if_index : 4 (en0)
  flags    : Scoped, Request A records
  reach    : Reachable
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Briefly speaking, a scoped DNS query can use only specified network interfaces (e.g. Ethernet or WiFi), while non-scoped can use any available interface.

More verbosely, an application that wants to resolve a name, sends a *request* (either scoped or non-scoped) to a resolver (usually a DNS client application), if the resolver does not have the answer cached, it sends a DNS *query* to a particular nameserver (and this goes through one interface, so it is always "scoped").

In your example resolver #1 "for scoped queries" can use only en0 interface (Ethernet).

Comment: So the application decides whether to make the query scoped or nonscoped? What is the default behavior, and/or which would `dig` or a web browser use?

Comment: An application like a web browser most probably queries the meta-resolver, which routes the queries to different resolvers according to rules described in resolver(5) manpage. Applications like `dig` or `host` make the queries directly to nameservers, not using the Mac OS X DNS query routing mechanism.

Comment: So, in this case both the application and the resolver can be viewed as **DNS client applications**? In theory, couldn't that nameserver be reached on more than one interface, and thus be non-scoped? - *... if the resolver does not have the answer cached, it sends a DNS query to a particular nameserver (and this goes through one interface, so it is always "scoped").*

Comment: @Shuzheng, yes, from the point of view of network both resolvers and applications like `dig` are DNS clients; a nameserver could be reachable by many interfaces, but I wouldn't call it "non-scoped" because is not its property, but merely a property of resolver and network configuration

Comment: @mik - thanks! Also, "**an application that wants to resolve a name, sends a request**", by *request*, do you mean a valid DNS query, or some custom platform-specific request?  Aren't most DNS nameservers also DNS clients? If they cannot answer the request, they will recursively ask the next nameserver in the chain? What's the difference between a resolver and a DNS nameserver? Is the only difference that a DNS nameserver corresponds to a domain, where as a resolver does not?

Comment: What if there exists both DNS configuration for scoped queries and non-scoped queries? Will the scoped configuration takes precedence then?